# Flex 3: How to Get More Content Indexed By Google?

Tags: xml, apache-flex

This is my Flex 3 website: [www.brainpinata.com](http://www.brainpinata.com) . Google's indexing the static content from the swf. If I look at the Keywords section of Google's Webmaster tools, I see a list of words from the static content. Unfortunately, all of my puzzles questions/answers are pulled from a mySQL database. So, Google misses 99% of the content.

I'm thinking of replacing the database service call with an embedded xml file in the swf. So I'd wrap the questions and answers in  tags in the Flex app. Currently the database has about 750 entries which is 552 KB. My goal is to have Google index more of my content.

a) Is this a dumb idea?

b) Would 550 KB of data in an XML file cause the Flex app to load so slowly that it will be annoying? If so, should I try a hybrid system: include only some puzzles in the XML file and the rest in the database? How many KB of XML is reasonable before loading the app becomes slow?

c) Any better ideas?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I wouldn't embed the XML in the Flex app; that just seems like a bad idea to me.  Maybe loading it dynammically.  Then google could index the "Static" XML file and you wouldn't bloat your SWF size.  I'm not sure if any of that would help SEO results, though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use hashbanged(#!) URLs in your Flex application and serve a crawler compatible version as detailed [here](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html). Google will fetch an alternate version of your web page depending on the path your provide after #!. Inside your crawlable page, you need to link to the other questions using hash fragments so that Google will find the other pages inside your Flex app and index them.

Answer (score 0):

If your site has unique urls for your content, you could generate a [sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) based on the database.